# Ajuda em select para criar novo input text

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho um campo select com mais ou menos 100 opçoes. Neste select atual, eu escolho uma opção e esta opção escolhida é preenchida em um novo input text...

Eu queria colocar um botão de "Mais" e ao ser clicado criar um novo campo input text... agora a minha dúvida: é possível usando o mesmo select eu fazer uma nova escolha e preencher esse novo campo sem perder oque foi preenchido no anterior?

Pesquisei e não achei nada que fizesse isso, se alguém puder me dar uma sugestão de como viabilizar isso, me ajudaria muito.

Exemplo:

```
<select class="form-control" id="frutas" name="frutas"  autofocus >
  <option value="">Selecione...</option>
  <option value="Maca">Maça</option>
  <option value="Uva">Uva</option>
  <option value="Morango">Morango</option>
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
</select>
```

E minha funçao:

```
$('#frutas').change(function () {                                                                                                                                                          $('#nome_fruta').val($('#frutas option:selected').text());
});
```

No exemplo acima, escolho uma fruta e ele preenche um input com o valor do select.
Agora eu queria colocar um botão pra criar um novo campo pra receber outra fruta do select.

Att

Comment: Você está usando algum framework (javascript puro, angular, react?) Também não consegui visualizar muito bem o que você precisa, se tiver algum desenho ajudaria a entender melhor.

Comment: @lfarroco estou usando bootstrap e jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu consegui entender da sua explicação, você quer fazer algo parecido com isso, certo?

```js
var count = 1;
$(document).on('change', '#opcao', function(){

  $('#valor'+count).val(this.value);
});

$(document).on('click', '#mais', function(){
  count++;
  var inputText = '<br><input type="text" id="valor'+count+'" value=""/>';
  $('#conteudo').append(inputText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Exemplo de Código</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="conteudo">
    <h1>Selecione uma opção</h1>
    <select id="opcao">
        <option>Selecione</option>
 <option value="opacao1">Opção1</option>
 <option value="opacao2">Opção2</option>
 <option value="opacao3">Opção3</option>
 <option value="opacao4">Opção4</option>
 <option value="opacao5">Opção5</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" id="mais">mais</a>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="valor1" value=""/>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: exato. Vou tentar modificar isso pra minha realidade. Nossa, como é legal saber JS...as vezes fico perdida. Obrigada

Comment: vc está usando javascript puro?

Comment: uso JQuery, mas busco na internet oque mais se aproxima doque preciso e escrevo depois.

Comment: Entendi! Bom, qualquer dúvida em relação ao código, sinta se a vontade em perguntar! ;)

Comment: obrigada. Uma dúvida, o jquery tem como eu implementar um botão pra remover o campo criado também?

Comment: Sim. e só usar: $('#idDoElementoCriado').remove();

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia a todos!

Fiz desse jeito abaixo. Está funcionando, queria por um botão de remover a linha (pra remover os dois inputs) e pelo que percebi, quando clico no link "mais" ele adiciona os dois campos que quero, mas a ordem fica estranha... tem como eu arrumar isso ou está certo?

```js
var count = 1;
$(document).on('change', '#fruta', function(){

  $('#nomeFruta'+count).val(this.value);
$('#descricao'+count).val();
});

$(document).on('click', '#mais', function(){
  count++;
 var inputText2 = '<br> <div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="nomeFruta">Fruta:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeFruta' + count + '" value=""/></div>';
                                                                        var inputText = '<br> <div class="form-group col-md-4"><label for="descricao">Descrição:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao' + count + '" value=""/></div>';
                                                                        $('#conteudo').append(inputText2);
                                                                        $('#conteudo').append(inputText);
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Modificando...</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <section id="conteudo">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="fruta">Escolha uma fruta</label>
    <select id="fruta">
        <option>Selecione</option>
 <option value="Maca">Maçã</option>
 <option value="Uva">Uva</option>
 <option value="Morango">Morando</option>
 <option value="Limao">Limão</option>
 <option value="Mexerica">Mexerica</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" id="mais">mais</a>
</div>
</section>
</div>
   <div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="nomeFruta">Fruta:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeFruta1" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="descricao">Descrição:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao1" value=""/>
</div>

</div>
  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```