# Campo input preenchido de acordo com o select escolhido

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma lista de opções na tag `select`, e eu quero mostrar um texto específico em um campo `input`, dependendo da opção escolhida no campo `select`.

Se for escolhida a opção "TRANSPARENTE" ou "FOSCO", o campo `input` "Orientação da Impressão", será preenchido com o texto "INTERNA". Se for escolhida a opção "PÉROLA" ou "METALIZADO", o `input` será preenchido com o texto "EXTERNA".

[image: Exemplo dos campos]

Código:

```html
<div id="banner-message" class="span3">
   <label for="substrato_imprime">Substrato (Impressão)<span class="required"></span></label>
   <select class="span12" name="substrato_imprime" id="substrato_imprime" style="text-transform:uppercase" value="">
      <option value="">Selecione</option>
      <option value="TRANSPARENTE">TRANSPARENTE</option>
      <option value="FOSCO">FOSCO</option>
      <option value="PEROLA">PÉROLA</option>
      <option value="METALIZADO">METALIZADO</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="span3">
   <label for="camada">Orientação da Impressão<span class="required"></span></label>
   <input class="span12" name="camada" id="camada" style="text-transform:uppercase" value="" >
</div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ajuda em select para criar novo input text](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155023/ajuda-em-select-para-criar-novo-input-text)

Comment: Júlio, por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Estes exemplos não são o que preciso. Segue o código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Pegue o valor do option
- Compare com os devidos valores
- injete no value do input o retorno do `if else`

```js
function associaInput() {
     var variavel;
    //pega o value do select
    var e = document.getElementById("substrato_imprime");
    var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    //injeta no value do input
    if (itemSelecionado=="TRANSPARENTE" || itemSelecionado=="FOSCO"){
        variavel="INTERNA";
    }else if (itemSelecionado=="PEROLA" || itemSelecionado=="METALIZADO"){
        variavel="EXTERNA";
    }
    document.getElementById('camada').value = variavel;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message" class="span3">
   <label for="substrato_imprime">Substrato (Impressão)<span class="required"></span></label>
   <select class="span12" name="substrato_imprime" id="substrato_imprime" style="text-transform:uppercase" onchange="javascript:associaInput();">
      <option value="">Selecione</option>
      <option value="TRANSPARENTE">TRANSPARENTE</option>
      <option value="FOSCO">FOSCO</option>
      <option value="PEROLA">PÉROLA</option>
      <option value="METALIZADO">METALIZADO</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="span3">
   <label for="camada">Orientação da Impressão<span class="required"></span></label>
   <input class="span12" name="camada" id="camada" style="text-transform:uppercase" value="" >
</div>
```